# Can the updater function in useState be redefined in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm working on a rather complex component that uses a store object. The data is local, so it doesn't warrant being added to my Redux store, but expensive enough that it shouldn't be calculated every render. I'm using `useState` to store and update this object. However, I have several functions regarding the store that I'd like to break out into a new file, including the updater function. For example, I'd like to do something akin to this:

```js
import { storeUpdater } from './ComponentStore.js';
function MyComponent(props) {
  const updateStore = storeUpdater;
  let storeState = useState({});
  const store = storeState[0];
  storeState[1] = updateStore;
  ...
}
```

Would this reliably work, and, more importantly, is it breaking any rules/anti-patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't work. You're just re-assigning `storeState[1]`, which you defined, to a different function, other than `setState` provided by `useState`. This code shouldn't update your `storeState[0]` at all.

Instead, you should make your `storeUpdater` function take `setState` function as an argument and provide it in this component.

`function storeUpdater(setState) {...}`

`const updateStore = () => storeUpdater(storeState[1])`

And then, inside your `updateStore`, do the desirable modifications to the `storeState` and then pass the new state to `setState`. If the new state depends on the previous state, you can use `setState(prevState => nextState)` syntax.